# Can we host Private Pages within SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion

In the previous CMS, we had the option to mark a page as Private & the front end server was able to redirect the end users to Login Page before making it available to the user.

Can we achieve something similar in SDL Web?

Similarly in case if we don't want to build login functionality but want to host Gated content where the user will first get a form & once provided the information like email address etc. will be redirected to the page he wanted to access?

Do we have any OOB feature in SDL Web or we need to build a Custom solution altogether?

Comment: For me bit unclear your question, do you looking to host the custom private pages in CME side or web app side?

Comment: Create the private pages in CME & publish on the web app, however, the pages should not be accessible directly i.e. users need to first fill some form with his basic information & then be able to view the target page.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (if I understand the question) is...

You can add metadata to content (Components) or to a Page Metadata and decorate the content/page access in the header with the appropriate code required on the website side.

As an example:

1. Page x = content

   - Template publishes with x = no script in the header (as a simple example) {1}
   - End result is user hits the page and sees it {2}
2. Page y = content + metadata flag indicating must be in group Y

   - Template publishes with y = script in the header to check if the user is a member of group Y {1}
   - End result is user redirected to authentication if not already authenticated {2}

*{1}* The application of the relevant code (or tagging if you're using DXA for example) is in the content/CME/rendering

*{2}* The logic is taken care of in your web app.